# UICollectionView deallocated instance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6.1

In the UICollectionView which i use,cellForItemAtIndexPath works perfectly and displays the collectionView initially.That is  collectionView.reloadData executes succesfully the first time.
When it is reloaded with the following code

```
[self.galleryCollectionView reloadData]
```

with the click of a button  it ends up in crash. I have enabled  the Zombie objects and it shows the error

```
[CVCell release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa4f26c0.
```

Following is the cellForItemAtIndexPath Method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionVieww cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCell";
CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionVieww dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.cellid=indexPath;
cell.delegate=self;
cell.containerImage.delegate=self;
return cell;
}
```

my ViewDidLoad calls the following method to create the collectionView.

```
-(void) createCollectionView
{

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
//This is the size of a single cell courtesy:varuns research.
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(179, 224)];
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing=45;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing=100;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 30, 20, 5);
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
self.galleryCollectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-120) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[ self.galleryCollectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
[self.galleryCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.galleryCollectionView setDelegate:self];

self.galleryCollectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [self.view addSubview:self.galleryCollectionView];
[self.galleryCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Any workaround to suggest?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In CreateCollectionView, do this:

```
CVCell *cell = [UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
[ self.galleryCollectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
[self.galleryCollectionView setDataSource:self];
```

Then, in cellForItemAtIndexPath, this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

That should do it, I think.  But I'm not sure what's going on where you're setting the cell.delegate, etc.  I'm not sure why one would ever do that but I guess it is possible.

Comment: I cant figure out the problem, but i by found that the problem occurs when the data source is empty, I bypassed the error by adding an empty  invisible cell !!!